# Sequel Pro can't connect to MySql database

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm new to mysql so bear with me please...

I installed mysql via homebrew and, after doing all the steps in mysql_secure_installation, I can connect to it in my terminal.
That's when I get this message:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.18 Homebrew
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

This means that it's installed and works correctly, right?

Ok, so now I open Sequel Pro and try to connect with a socket connection. I put 'root' in the username field. I added my password that I set up in the mysql_secure_installation in the password field. But then I get this error:
[Sequel Pro Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k29c.jpg)

Did I do something wrong in the installation? Did I forget to install something?
Or is this because of something else?

How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 8 uses `caching_sha2_password` by default. Sequel Pro might not support this authentication plugin.

To use the previous authentication plugin run:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'yourhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpw';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
QUIT
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for others, Sequel Pro has fixed the issue while connecting to Mysql 8.

You can download the build # a2e6c1198d (or any Complete Build after) from https://sequelpro.com/test-builds.

Comment: good job , It solved my problem